# React Native ejected expo app is crashing in simulator

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an app that started failing recently when I am trying to start it in XCode.
Initially I thought it’s some of my recent changes that caused this, but neither rolling back the repository, nor re-ejecting it helped.

Finally, I managed to minimally reproduce it:

```
expo init myawsomeapp
cd myawesomeapp
yarn start (runs in simulator well)
expo eject (choose eject to expokit)
cd ios; pod install
open ios/myawesomeapp.xcworkspace in XCode
start the app in simulator
```

[image]

Crash:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
    0x7fff523bc7f0 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000148 
    0x7fff523bc7f5 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x7fff523bc7f8 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x7fff523bc7fa <+10>: jae    0x7fff523bc804            ; <+20>
    0x7fff523bc7fc <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff523bc7ff <+15>: jmp    0x7fff523b6a89            ; cerror_nocancel
    0x7fff523bc804 <+20>: retq   
    0x7fff523bc805 <+21>: nop    
    0x7fff523bc806 <+22>: nop    
    0x7fff523bc807 <+23>: nop
```

Is anyone else facing it too? 
Any advice on troubleshooting this would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you run it in xcode, you need to run expo start in project root, because it will search for the development url to download the bundle code, if it does not work, you can run expo start before pod install and keep it running

Comment: Hi, in my case its getting the full download and then crashing. Any thoughts?

Comment: Any error messages?, if it crashes after downloading, then there might be javascript error inside Your code somewhere, or missing dependency, i personally removed expo and will never use it again

Comment: none. i started with this command `react-native run-ios --verbose` and dont see any errors at all. only debug, info-s. And finally it says

`
debug ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **


success Successfully built the app
info Installing "/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bcoihgfgrwwnpjanyjtizpteqnth/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ios.app"
info Launching "io.bf.ios"
success Successfully launched the app on the simulator`

Comment: The app starts in the simulator opensup, and then dies by itself. The expo is running in project root

Answer (score 0):

If your code is still simple, manually clone to CLI. Because if you use Eject, later there will be quite a lot of errors related to Podfile and Packages. I have been a victim of this. Happy code. ..

Comment: The thing is that the application was ejected before and was working fine in ejected mode. I have seen the same error once previously and reejecting it helped/
By reejecting I mean:
rm -rf ios && rm -rf android && expo eject && ...

Now it doesn't help and the problem doesn't want to go away

Comment: I am new to expo eject. can you kindly explain the steps in detail. what isthe CLI in question. how do i copy? is it git clone etc?

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped me. Just incase somebody comes here with the same issue.

I had to do expo publish and then when i run `react-native run-ios` from the folder containing the `ios/` things started to work. My expo version is 4.2.1 ; npm version is 7.0.2 ;